# force redirect http to https in aws lightsail loadbalancer

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elb, amazon-lightsail

Website Server : Windows IIS
Environment : AWS lightsail with loadbalancer

i have created a sample webapp in iis and in lightsail load balancer i have verified my domain and enabled https and also created a win-acme certificate in my iis server certificate and added https in bindings ( port 443) everything seems fine my webapp works fine until this . Now i used url rewrite module to force https over http using the below link
https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/
Now the webapp wont load inside or outside the server but if i enter http://demo.example.com/  it redirects to https://demo.example.com// automatically but my webapp is not working it shows error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" note : it was working fine untill url rewrite !!  need help TIA Guys

extras : i tried the same above steps but without the lightsail loadbalancer then the forced url redirect works fine meaning i am unable to redirect loadbalancer traffic to https but normal traffic can be redirected fine . but for security i need a loadbalancer in front of my webapp

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed information.

Comment: [Possible duplication](https://serverfault.com/questions/1026989/how-to-forward-http-to-https-with-lightsail-load-balancer) in serverfault.com